# I can't run rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to use rviz, but recently I receive the following error:

```
[ INFO] [1328487732.257914711]: rviz revision number 1.6.7
[ INFO] [1328487732.258118438]: ogre_tools revision number 1.6.2
[ INFO] [1328487732.258162578]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1328487732.492394503]: Loading general config from [/home/jabrena/.rviz/config]
[ INFO] [1328487732.493823666]: Loading display config from [/home/jabrena/.rviz/display_config]
[ INFO] [1328487732.598258030]: RTT Preferred Mode is PBuffer.
do_wait: drmWaitVBlank returned -1, IRQs don't seem to be working correctly.
Try adjusting the vblank_mode configuration parameter.
[ INFO] [1328487733.190865822]: Texture for pass 0: creating with size 1 x 1
Segmentation fault
```

How to modify the parameter vblank_mode? What is the right value?

Many thanks in advance.

Juan Antonio

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12898/i-can%27t-run-rviz/) by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2012-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/Troubleshooting#Segfault_during_startup

---

Originally posted by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) with karma: 274 on 2012-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-02-06**:
That's just a warning that a piece of meta-information in the message was not filled out properly.

**Comment by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on 2012-02-05**:
Shell show the following warning: Message received without callerid. What is the meaning?